# How to get the references of a project in Visual Studio Extensions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How to get the references of a project in Visual Studio Extensions ?

I think that the IVsReferenceProviderContext interface could be used to get the referenced project names. But how could I get this interface object from IVsProject or IVsHierarchy or anything else ?